# powerbi : slicer on date but with blank

Tags: powerbi

I've a table with some datas and one of them is a date format, but some rows have "blank" date.
I would like to use date slicer to show rows in a period (so date slice with 'between' format) BUT with always the blank data.

So, for example, if my slicer is a selecte period between 15 July and 16 July, I want to show all rows with a date field in this period but also all the blank rows.

How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance for all the help

Comment: How do you find a null value between two non-null values? Add a date to the null values and or switch how you filter the data.

Comment: adding a date to replace the "null" is not a solution: it modifies what is represented and you would have to dynamically modify the date according to the slicer, unless you have a solution to do this dynamically, this is not an approach in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using "Between" mode for a date slicer, Its always required 2 parameter Start and End date as shown in the below image-

[image]

As a result, you can not include NULL values inside a date range as NULL is not a date. But, if you use "Dropdown" mode for the date slicer - you will get the option of including NULL values as well in the list. You need to make Multi selection option on to select more dates from the list. You can select NULL + All dates from the range you wants to set as date range (as shown in the below image)

[image]

> **Note:** Definitely its a worst solution in case of bigger date range.

Comment: I know this (otherwise I wouldn't have asked), but the drop-down list won't be useful for what I want (because it contains a lot of data range). I'm looking for a way (a workaroung) to have the slicer in the "intermediate" version and include the blank.

Comment: Hi @Efhache, you will get some useful information here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_117Mwmw2c

Comment: Not exactly what I need but was the right way to find, thanks